# Keycloak INTROSPECT_TOKEN event sessionId is null

Tags: java, keycloak

I've created an event listener plugin and installed on Keycloak. I'm listening to `INTROSPECT_TOKEN` events and they are useless because there is not any information from user or session. I'm trying to get `userId` or `sessionId` but it returns `null`.

```
@Override
public void onEvent(Event event) {
    LOGGER.info("EventType: " + event.getType());
    LOGGER.info("UserID: " + event.getUserId());
    LOGGER.info("SessionID: " + event.getSessionId());
}
```